# qTip and windows 7 tooltip style

Tags: jquery, css, windows-7

I am using qTip to add some custom control over my websites tooltips. I'd like to set a custom css design that will look the same as windows 7. I can't for the hell of it, mimic the looks and feels of it though.

does anyone know If windows 7 saves custom css files for web browsers somewhere? If not, how else can I mimic a reasonable similar style?

Comment: A screenshot of what you're after would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to try to mimic the Win7 tooltip, you can use the CSS class underneath. It utilizes CSS3, so it won't work well in older browsers.

```
.tooltip {
          font-family: "Segoe UI", tahoma, verdana, sans serif;
            font-size: 10px;
               border: 1px solid #89898b;
            max-width: 300px;
                color: #535353;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #eaeaf0);
     background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #ffffff),color-stop(1, #eaeaf0));
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #eaeaf0);
     background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #eaeaf0);
               filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#eaeaf0');
      -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #535353;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #535353;
           box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #535353;
              padding: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
        border-radius: 2px;

}
```

You can see a sample of the CSS class [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z5zsj/5/).

Comment: inetersting, do you know how to achieve this in css 2 though?

Comment: You can always use images instead of the css3 effects, but it will unfortunately be much more complicated. You may, for example, use a gradient image as the background image, but it won't scale well. This class will work fine in most browsers, including older IE-versions. The only difference is that some of them may not show the gradients, shadows and round corners.